# PayPal buttons with multiple currencies using react-paypal-js

Tags: reactjs, paypal

Try to change my currency, but when I use currency_code: 'EUR' I'm getting this error:

Error: Unexpected currency: EUR passed to order.create. Please ensure you are passing /sdk/js?currency=EUR in the paypal script tag.

When I go only with the currency: 'EUR' from the initialOptions and remove it from the PayPalButtons then it is using the Amount in USD and change it to EUR. But not everything is in Euro.

```
const initialOptions = {
  'client-id': 'test',
  currency: 'EUR',
  intent: 'capture',
};

<PayPalScriptProvider options={initialOptions}>
    <PayPalButtons
        createOrder={(data, actions) => {
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                                  description:
                                    'Rechnung ' +
                                    dayjs(date, 'MM/YYYY').format('MMMM YYYY'),
                                  amount: {
                                    currency_code: 'EUR',
                                    value: 2
                                }]
               

                                    
/>
</PayPalScriptProvider>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But not everything is in Euro.

In the current JS SDK design, rendering buttons for different currencies requires separate SDK loads.

When loading the SDK yourself, the `data-namespace` attribute can be added at script load time. I don't see support for this in the react-paypal-js documentation.

```html
<h3>USD buttons...</h3>
<div id="paypal-button-container-1" />

<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD" data-namespace="paypalUSD"></script>
<script>
    paypalUSD.Buttons({
        //...
    }).render('#paypal-button-container-1');
</script>


<hr />


<h3>EUR buttons...</h3>
<div id="paypal-button-container-2" />

<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=EUR" data-namespace="paypalEUR"></script>
<script>
    paypalEUR.Buttons({
        //...
    }).render('#paypal-button-container-2');
</script>
```

While there's nothing in the documentation, looking at the package code for react-paypal-js it does seem it may be supported. You'll need separate PayPalScriptProviders, each with their own currency and `data-namespace` value (default is `paypal`)

Comment: I'm sorry I don't fully understand your answer. What do you mean about requires seperate SDK loads. Is there a solution to use Euro?

Comment: (The USD and the EUR buttons needed separate SDK script loads, aka separate <PayPalScriptProviders> when using react, and each one must have a separate namespace or they won't work on the same page)